# Xcode debugger doesn't work for a project with multiple targets

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging, intellisense, multitargeting

I have an Xcode project with many targets. Some files are added to all targets, some to only one. The debugger stopped working, also the intellisense sometimes works, sometimes doesn't.

Have anyone ever had the same problem?

EDIT: Cleaning the project solved the debugger issue. But the intellisense still doesn't work.

Comment: Would you like to include a screenshot of "stopped working" so that we could know what's wrong?

Comment: please provide more info.

Comment: Cleaning the project solved the debugger issue. But the intellisense still doesn't work.